# nested function in function w/ for loop

Tags: python-3.x

New to python but practicing on returning a list in sorted order w/out using the sort function. In combining a few pieces of code, I made it work but not sure I understand what I did. I was wondering if somebody could explain my return function under the else statement?

```
l=[9,7,1,8]
def sortedLists1(list1):
    if len(list1) <= 1:
        return list1
    else:
        return sortedLists1([n for n in list1[1:] if n <= list1[0]])+\ 
               [list1[0]]+sortedLists1([n for n in list1[1:] if n > list1[0]])

print(sortedLists1(l))
```

Comment: that's a quicksort (pivot=list1[0])

Answer (score 0):

```
sortedLists1([n for n in list1[1:] if n <= list1[0]])+\ 
               [list1[0]]+sortedLists1([n for n in list1[1:] if n > list1[0]])
```

This has 3 parts:

  1.

```
[ n for n in list1[1:] if n <= list1[0] ]
```

Here you find all numbers in `list1` that are `<=` `list1[0]` thereby sorting the element `list1[0]`. You then create a list of all the elements that are `<=` `list1[0]` and pass them to be sorted into `sortedList1`.

```
sortedLists1([n for n in list1[1:] if n <= list1[0]])
```

This does the same thing and recursively sorts the list up to `list1[0]`. You now have a list of sorted elements that does not include `list1[0]`

  2.

```
[list1[0]]
```

Since you have already sorted all elements until `list1[0]` all you have to do is add this element to the end of sorted list. So now all elements in your list up to and including `list1[0]` is sorted.

3.

```
sortedLists1([n for n in list1[1:] if n > list1[0]])
```

This  does the opposite of the `1.`. It recursively sorts all elements of `list1` after `list1[0]`. It finds all elements `>` `list1[0]` and gives you that list.

You now have to add this list to the previous sorted list and you get your answer a fully sorted list.